# Define file with Class and interface raised error expected ';'

Tags: typescript

I want to create Typescript file which contains class and interface:

```
export class Merchant {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public state_raw: string,
    public users: string,
  ) {}
};

export interface MerchantList {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public state_raw: string,
    public users: string,
  ) {}
};
```

But I have error:
';' expected. at this line `) {}`. Can you give me some advice how I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since an interface just declares properties and methods that may be implemented by another type, it cannot have a constructor.  You probably meant:

```
export interface MerchantList {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  state_raw: string;
  users: string;
};
```